# Initialize two dimension char array with string array

Tags: c#, string, multidimensional-array, char, initialization

I have a syntax issue: the following line is OK:

```
char[,] board = new char[2, 2] { { '1', '2' }, { '3', '4' } };
```

but if I have a string array and try this:

```
char[,] board = new char[2, 2] { "12".ToCharArray(), "34".ToCharArray() };
```

It gives me error: CS0846   A nested array initializer is expected.
What should be the correct syntax as I have long strings and don't use the char syntax in the first sample?

Comment: Try this : char[,] board = { { '1', '2' }, { '3', '4' } };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C# language has special syntax to recognize multi-dimensional arrays. While the syntax looks very similar to that seen for initialization of jagged arrays (e.g. something like `char[][]`), you can't use the syntax to perform initialization from other objects.

In your example, the syntax with the string literals would work if you were initializing a jagged array (or rather, something similar to it would: `char[][] board2 = new char[][] { "12".ToCharArray(), "34".ToCharArray() };`), but for initialization of multi-dimensional arrays on variable declaration, you have to use the nested array initializers because you're not initializing individual objects within a single-dimensional array as you are with jagged arrays.

The compiler needs to be able to generate all of the initialization for the single object at compile time, and it has no way to do that when you try to initialize the two-dimensional array using arrays obtained at run-time using the `ToCharArray()` method).

So, you'll have to do it the hard way. For example:

```
string[] rows = { "12", "34" };

for (int i = 0; i < rows.Length; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < rows[i].Length; j++)
    {
        board[i, j] = rows[i][j];
    }
```

You can encapsulate that logic in a method if you expect to have to write code like that frequently. For example:

```
private static void InitBoard(char[,] board, params string[] rows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows.Length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < rows[i].Length; j++)
        {
            board[i, j] = rows[i][j];
        }
}
```

Called like this:

```
char[,] board = new char[2,2];

InitBoard(board, "12", "34");
```